# Como inverter um arrey usando um procedimento em C

Tags: c, array

```
float inverterArray(float vetor[20]);
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    float a[20];
    int j = 20;
    printf("Esses são os elementos da array antes de invertidos:\n");
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i ++)
    {
        a[i] = rand();
        printf("%d - %2.f\n",i,a[i]);
    }
    printf("Esses são os elementos da array depois de invertidos:\n");
    j = 0 ;
    a[20] = inverterArray(a);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i ++)
    {
        printf("%d - %2.f\n",i,a[j]);
    }

}

float inverterArray(float vetor[20])
{
    int i,n = 20;
    float vetorInv[20];
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        vetorInv[i]=vetor[n-1];
        n--;
    }
    for (i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i ++)
    {
        vetor[i] = vetorInv[i];
        return vetor[i];
    }

}
```

Estou tentando fazer um programa que invirta uma array de valores aleatórios, sendo que a parte de inverter o array "a" deve ser um proecedimento que deve retornar o resultado no mesmo array antes enviado.
ex:a[1,2,3] -> a[3,2,1]

Contudo, estou com um problema de que o programa retorna somente um valor -  mais expecificamente o último valor da array "a" em toda a array "a".
ex:a[1,2,3]  -> a[3,3,3]

Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score -3):

```
float inverterArray(float vetor[20]);
 int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    float a[20];
    int j = 20;
    printf("Esses são os elementos da array antes de invertidos:\n");
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i ++)
    {
        a[i] = rand();
        printf("%d - %2.f\n",i,a[i]);
    }
    printf("Esses são os elementos da array depois de invertidos:\n");
    inverterArray(a,&a);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i ++)
    {
        printf("%d - %2.f\n",i,a[i]);
    }

}

void inverterArray(float vetor[20], float *a[20])
{
    int i,n = 20;
    float vetorInv[20];
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        vetorInv[i]=vetor[n-1];
        n--;
    }
    for (i = 0 ; i < 20 ; i ++)
    {
        vetor[i] = vetorInv[i];

    }

}
```

Esse é uma maneira que eu encontrei para corrigir o bug